# I recently upgraded my project from Next.js 12 to Next.js 13 and now I am facing memory leakage issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Whenever I start working on a project in development mode, after some time, I encounter this warning: **The server is running out of memory, restarting to free up memory.** and server stops I have to manually restart it. I am using app directory for my project.

I looked into this GitHub issue [Github issue link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46756), but it didn't help me. I tried the suggested solutions, but I'm still experiencing the same issue.

One thing I have noticed is that when I migrated from Next.js 12 to Next.js 13, the number of modules have increased.

In Next.js 12:

```
Event: Compiled client and server successfully in 5 seconds (757 modules)
```

In Next.js 13:

```
Event: Compiled client and server successfully in 4 seconds (1273 modules)
```

Could you please let me know if this issue is specific to development or if it also occurs in production? If it's related to importing unnecessary modules, I'm hopeful that tree shaking will take care of it during the build process.